# How can I correctly close the application opened with using of Process?

Tags: c#

I open the application using the Process class:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process vsProc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
vsProc.StartInfo.FileName = "program.exe";
vsProc.Start();
```

If I just kill it `vsProc.Kill()` the application ends uncorrectly. How can I close it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of the reason it is ending incorrectly is that you have not freed all of the resources associated with it prior to killing it. Try using the [CloseMainWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx)and [Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close.aspx) methods. CloseMainWindow will send a close message to the specified applicaitions main window, and Close() should free resources associated with the process.

Answer (score 2):

How to close a program 'correctly' depends 100% on the program you're dealing with. If you're the one writing the child program, you get to implement proper & sane behavior. If not, your best **general** bet is finding the application's main window and send it a close request... rather than terminating the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wait for the application to finish its job and then continue with the parent process, then you can call [WaitForExit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx) on it. If it is a non-terminating app then what do you mean by it 'ends incorrectly'?

Answer (score 0):

vsProc.Close();

Frees all resources associated with this component. Also get JetBrains ReSharper...

Comment: What does resharper have to do with anything?

Comment: It makes it easier to find these methods.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `vsProc` has a main window and will cleanly end the program if the window is closed, you could use the steps [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mrmohankumar/closewindow01312008055929AM/closewindow.aspx). If you don't know the title or the title is dynamic, use `vsProc.MainWindowTitle`. You can skip the FindWindow step by just making a call to `vsProc.MainWindowHandle` and using the resulting value to call the SendMessage command.